# Getting the value of an object in a TFL API array

Tags: javascript, api

I've created a map in Leaflet of bike points in London using TFL's API, and I want to add more than just the name of the bikepoints in the pop-up window boxes I've created, specifically the number of bikes and empty docks at each bikepoint. I know which point in the array represents each value, but when I designate it in pop-up array, it shows undefined. I've tried the Number() function to get value, but then I get NaN.

How can I get the value of the object I want from this API?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get(
      "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint?app_id=" + '1728116f' + "&app_key=" + '81829e2aee19d388098b671096ba2242',
      cluster
    );

    function cluster(addressPoints) {
      var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
          maxZoom: 19,
          attribution: '<a href="https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Maps_Terms_of_Use">Wikimedia</a>'
        }),
        latlng = L.latLng(51.50698622240712, -0.11160135269165039);

      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 13,
        layers: [tiles]
      });

      var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

      for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat, a.lon), {
          title: a.commonName
        });
        marker.bindPopup(a.commonName
      + '</b><br />' + 'Number of available bikes: ' + Number(a.additionalProperties[6][5]))
      + '</b><br />' + 'Number of empty docks: ' + Number(a.additionalProperties[7][5]);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
      }

      map.addLayer(markers);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: are you saying these: a.additionalProperties[6][5] and a.additionalProperties[7][5] are coming up as [object]?

Comment: whoops sorry, it came up as object when i did something else. when i write in a.additionalProperties[6][5] and a.additionalProperties[7][5], "undefined" is written in out in the pop up box! i've edited my post accordingly

Comment: `a.additionalProperties[6]` is not an array, itz an object. You may need to read the value property from it `Number(a.additionalProperties[6].value)`

Comment: wow you're totally right, that fixed it! thank you so much!